# how to decode the encoded array value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I want to decode the array value in web service.I need to decode '`CONTENT_VALUES`' field which has name and value as its object and pass it in `json.ID` and `USER_ID` return correct `value(separate field)` but name and question returns null. I want to decode 
 `'ques' => $datas->name, 'answer' => $datas->value`.value of CONTENT_VALUES=[{"name":"radio","value":"","sur_id":"3","user_id":"admin@gmail.com","pagename":"question_response"},{"name":"true","value":""}]

```
$query1 = mysql_query("select * from `$prefix.response` where ID='$sur_id'");
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $content = $fetch['CONTENT_VALUES'];
    $datas = json_decode($content);
    $test[] = array('ID' => $fetch['ID'], 'USERID' => $fetch['USER_ID'], 'ques' => $datas->name, 'answer' => $datas->value);
}
```

Comment: show sample data of $fetch['CONTENT_VALUES'];

Comment: Maybe `$fetch['CONTENT_VALUES']` is not valid `JSON`?!

Comment: dont use the old, deprecated mysql-extension (like mysql_query). use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php.

This will describe how to convert a JSON string into a PHP object or array.

When you get stuck more with this you can fairly simple google "php decode json" and find plenty helpful resources.

Edit: Read the question too quick just before and understood it wrong, have you tried checking the return result of your `$datas = json_decode($content)` statement? Does `CONTENT_VALUES` actually contain JSON encoded data? Does the decoded object actually contain `name` and `value`?

Answer (score 1):

May be you should set use mb_convert_encoding before decoding like this

```
$content = $fetch['CONTENT_VALUES'];
$content_value= mb_convert_encoding($content ,"UTF-8");
$datas = json_decode($content_value);
```

Comment: still having problem sir.

Comment: now it return array as [{"ID":"2","USERID":"admin@gmail.com","ques":[{"name":"comment","value":"comment me for the reason","sur_id":"1","user_id":"admin@gmail.com","pagename":"question_response"},{"name":"check-box[]","value":"1"},{"name":"radio","value":"radio 2"},{"name":"yes","value":"no"},{"name":"date","value":"2015-10-23"},{"name":"select-deopdown","value":""},{"name":"true","value":"false"},{"name":"number","value":"55"}]}]

Comment: I want to take name and value in angular js controller

Comment: did you get the values for $datas->name?

Comment: post your angular js part as separate question.

Comment: $datas->name return null

Comment: what is the array you posted in comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93160/discussion-between-user3386779-and-arun-krish).